how query and find raw in many to many on pivot table
I have 2 table with many to many and pivot table ,
Sku and attribute_value
SKU table :



id
code




1
sku1


2
sku2


3
sku3



Attribute value



id
name




1
Red


2
Blue


3
Black


4
Pink


5
Big


6
Small



Pivot Table :



id
sku_id
att_value




1
1
2


2
1
5


2
2
2


2
2
6


2
3
3


2
3
6



Now my problem is : how can i find the sku_id when I have 2 att_value (ex : 2 & 6 ) ( Blue and Small )
Sku::whereHas('Attributevalue', function ($query)  {
        $query->whereIn('sh_sku_attribute.attribute_id',[2,6]  ) ;
             })->first() ;



Take a look at orWhere() in the documentation.

One way you could go about this is to define a model for the pivot table and declare belongsTo relationships to both tables i.e SKU and Attribute.
class PivotTable extends Pivot{

    public function sku(): belongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sku::class);
    }

    public function attribute(): belongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
    }
} 

After this, you can access both table or models directly from each other through the pivot by creating a relationship to both models directly on each as shown below
SKU MODEL:
class SKU extends Model{

    public function attributes(): hasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Attribute::class,
            PivotTable::class,
            'sku_id,
            'id', 'id', 'attribute_id'
        );
    }
} 

Attribute MODEL:
class Attribute extends Model{

    public function sku(): hasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Sku::class,
            PivotTable::class,
            'attribute_id,
            'id', 'id', 'sku_id'
        );
    }
} 

Afterwhich, you can get the sku model having attributes of both 2 and 6 ids.
$attributeIds = [2, 6];
$sku = SKU::whereHas('attributes', function($query) use($attributeIds){
             $query->whereIn('id', $attributeIds);
         }, ‘=‘, count($attributesIds))
         ->get();

But, if you are only concerned with getting just the sku id then you can pluck the id from the $sku variable above i.e
$sku_ids = $sku->pluck('id');


Hello,
Thank you for your helpful response.
The problem arises when we use whereIn. In this case, it uses OR instead of AND, which is why the correct result isn't applied. For example, if I'm looking for attribute_id 2 and 6 in the provided table, the output is sku_id 2 and 3, whereas I'm only looking for 2, since only that row has attribute_id equal to 2 and 6.

ooh, I see! Then,  after defining the models and relationships as I have mentioned above, The solution up there from your original post should now work with a little twig to it. I will edit my comment now to reflect the correct approach to it..Many cheers.

Thank you again for taking the time to help. However, the issue isn't just about receiving the ID and using pluck. For example, since we've used whereIn and applied the array [2,6], your code outputs all three sku_ids that exist in the table. The reason for this is the use of 'OR', because all three sku_ids are related to either 2 or 6 in the relational table. But I'm only looking for the sku_id with the number 2, as this is the only item that is related to both 2 and 6. Did I manage to explain my problem clearly?

Apologies for the late reply, I have now updated the section to filter the rows to where sku has both attributes. I am not presently with my pc to test this but I believe this should suit your needs.
